Messaging functionality between customers and vendors
I have a WooCoomerce shop and using WCFM multivendor marketplace.
I'd like to have messaging functionality between customers and vendor (or essentially between registered accounts). I'd tried the built-in modules of WCFM but I cannot make them work or they don't cover my needs.
Is there any plugin (for free if there's any) that just gives a simple messaging option with having access to historical chats and maybe e-mail notifications upon new messages?
